# Easiest way to circumvent API response spec violations in C# REST-Client

Tags: c#, json, rest, magento, magento2

I am currently tasked with implementing a tool that communicates with the [REST-API of Magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)

Magento2 provides a [Swagger 2.0 JSON schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/schemas/latest-2.2.schema.json) that allowed me (after fixing numerous issues in the schema) to generate a proper client using NSwag.

The problem now is: The [Magento 2 REST API](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) is not following its own spec at some points.

I solved some problems already by manually fixing the generated code.
However, i constantly hit new problems due to the spec not matching the reality in regards of type.

For example, the schema specifies:

```
"framework-attribute-interface": {
    "type": "object",
    "description": "Interface for custom attribute value.",
    "properties": {
        "attribute_code": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Attribute code"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Attribute value"
        }
    },
    "required": ["attribute_code", "value"]
}
```

however, the actual API may return a `string` or an `array` as shown by this example snippet of the response:

```
{
    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
    "value": ["6", "8", "16"]
}, {
    "attribute_code": "required_options",
    "value": "0"
}
```

While i could spend days to test the whole API and fix everything, i want to avoid this for obvious reasons (time).
The question now thus is wether or not there is some easy, lazy way to "auto convert" everything (want to avoid `dynamic` btw.)?

The JSON framework used is `Newtonsoft.Json`.
Communication works via the `.NET Framework` `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

Comment: Have you considered that changing the schema is where you messed up? The response might not be correct according to your schema, but as far as the API is concerned, with its schema, it is?

Comment: The fixes in the schema are related to duplucate `operationId`, it is a known issue but they never fixed it. So i highly doubt that those changes have been the issues as the types never have been touched.

Comment: Then a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) might be what you need

Comment: How to apply them globally and only on type conflicts? Because the above only serves as one of many occasions sadly ...

Comment: There is the `JsonConverter<T>` class for a generic implementation. Then you just need to use it when actually deserliaizing

Comment: was actually talking about applying it literally on every possible property, because otherwise i still need to manually find and fix those occasions

Comment: What about [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)? You could also, if you wanted, create a custom attribute if you ever get a property you don't want to apply it to